# Google Sheets Email Automation when cell reaches certain value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get google sheets to automatically send me an email when the value in column C reaches 8. I want the email message to pull the name of the person which is in column A of the row where the value in column C is now 8. The value is the result of a formula, which is counting the number of google form submissions by a certain person. I've tried a bunch of different formulas, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Formula:

```
function check102Logs(e) {
    // Fetch the 102 logs
    const sourcesheet =    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Overall").getDataRange().getValues(); 
   // Check total 102 log number
   if (e.range.columnStart != 3 || e.value != "8") return;
    // Send email alert
        let data = sourcesheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,1)
        let name = data[0][0]
        let now = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US");
       let message = name + " completed 8 102 logs on " + now + ". You should reach out to them about their written assessment and how they feel about solo ground facilitation.";
        Logger.log(message);
       MailApp.sendEmail("myemail@gmail.com", "102 Logs Completed", message);
   }
```

From my understanding, Google Sheets onEdit trigger won't work with formula changes, so I was using a time driven trigger:

```
 function create102Trigger() {
   ScriptApp.newTrigger("check102Logs")
  .timeBased()
  .atHour(12)
  .nearMinute(20)
  .everyDays(1)
  .inTimezone("America/New_York")
  .create();
 }
```

I'm learning this as I go, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi and welcome. It's not clear what EXACTLY is your question. May I clarify... you have a Spreadsheet containing a Form Response sheet; in second sheet you have formulas to display the unique Response Names and the count of responses for each name. When/if the count = 8, you want to send an email. You said "I've tried a bunch of different formulas, but I can't seem to get it to work." So... is your question "how to create the list of names & count of responses? OR "how to trigger the email", &/OR "how to ensure that you don't send duplicate emails"? OR "all of the above"?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response.. Yes, I have a spreadsheets containing form response sheet and on a second sheet, formulas to count the responses for a corresponding name.  I'm trying to trigger the email when the count of responses reaches 8.

Answer (score 0):

This single script answers all the possible aspects of the OP scenario:

- Triggered by Installable `OnFormSubmit`
- uses Event Objects to identify the submitted response and the Name

  - `var submittedRow = e.range.rowStart`
  - `var formName = e.namedValues['Name']`
- uses a function to count all the instances of the submitted name in the list of all response names

  - `var respCount = finder(newrespName, flatRespNames)`
- dynamically evaluates the number of responses (`resCount`)

  - this removes any need to write a value to confirm that an email has been sent
  - if the count equals 8, then the script can be modified to send an email
  - if the count is NOT equal to 8, then no email is sent.
  - caters for the situation where the number of instances for any given name is greater than 8

---

**Visual Count**

[image: visual count]

If a visual count is required, then use this formula. Enter the following in cell A3.

`=query({'Form Responses 1'!B2:B},"select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 <>'' group by Col1 order by count(Col1) desc label count(Col1) ''")`

---

```
// send an email if the response is the eight response for the given name.
// assumes a one question Google Form
// Response sheet shows "Timestamp" in Column A; "Name" in Column B
// Create Installable Trigger - On Form Submit

function sendEmail(e) {
  
  var responses = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
   
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG

  // get the source range
  var submittedRow = e.range.rowStart
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: The submitted row = "+submittedRow)

  // get the name of the person whio submitted the rersponse
  var formName = e.namedValues['Name']
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the name is "+formName)
  // create a temporary array
  var respName = []
  // push the name onto the array
  respName.push(formName)
  // Logger.log(respName) // DEBUG
  // convert the temporary array to 1D
  var newrespName = respName.flat(1); //The depth level specifying how deep a nested array structure should be flattened. Defaults to 1.
  // Logger.log(newrespName) // DEBUG

  // get all the names from the responses
  //var mailLR = mailList.getLastRow() // get the last row of data
  var respNames= responses.getRange(2,2,submittedRow-1).getValues()
  // Logger.log(respNames) // DEBUG
  // Logger.log("the names range = "+mailList.getRange(2,2,mailLR-1).getA1Notation())
  var flatRespNames = respNames.map(function(e){return e[0];});//[[e],[e],[e]]=>[e,e,e]
  // Logger.log(flatRespNames) // DEBUG
  var respCount = finder(newrespName, flatRespNames)
  Logger.log("DEBUG: Submitted by: "+formName+", submission#="+respCount)

  if (respCount == 8){
    // send email
    Logger.log("DEBUG: Send Email")
  }
  else{
    // don't send email
    Logger.log("DEBUG: Do NOT send Email")

  }

}

function finder(search, target) {
    return search.map(function (val) {
        return target.filter(function (e) {
            return val === e;
        }).length;
    });
}
```